# Cutting with ffmpeg, video got wrong colors and pixaleted frames?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, resolution

After cutting and concatenating with:

```
ffmpeg i- example.mp4 -ss 01:02 -to 03:01 -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.mp4
```

it looks like the video changed resolution at some time and got wrong colors and pixaleted frames, source file was deleted, is it possible to repair it extracting the raw data?

I tried to use the `-vf scale` filter to see if it gets other results, but stills the same.

Using `ffmpeg -fflags +igndts` I got:

> Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 399777, current: 399767; changing to 399778. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file."

Comment: Please show the entire command line output from ffmpeg. Your command is wrong – `i-` does not make sense as an option.